# Is any copying happening here?

Tags: c++, pointers

As I understand it, you can't return an array from a method because you are actually returning a pointer to data created in the method's scope. There's no guarantee that the data will still be at the address pointed to by that pointer outside the method scope.

But it seems to work for constructors because this code prints true every time I run it. Am I just getting lucky?

```cpp
class Vector3d {

    public:
        float* data_ptr;

    public:
        Vector3d(float values[3]) {
            data_ptr = values;
        }
        
};

int main(){
    float arr[] = {3, 4, 5};
    Vector3d vec = Vector3d(arr);
    
    cout << (vec.data_ptr[0] == arr[0]) << endl;
}
```

I think my other option is to make the member variable an array instead of a pointer and use a "copy" constructor:

```cpp
class Vector3d {

    public:
        float data_ptr[3];

    public:
        Vector3d(float values[3]) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                data_ptr[i] = values[i];
            }
        }
        
};
```

Does that mean that `data_ptr[i]` and `values[i]` are now two distinct values stored at distinct memory addresses? Or are those variables sharing a memory location?

Comment: Your first (and "lucky") example works because you're passing `arr` as a parameter. As the pointer variable is created on the main loop, it will only be deallocated from the stack after the main block ends. That's why it looks like luck. If you try calling this from inside a function or another block scope (and make sure the float pointer that will be passed as parameter will be created in there), the result may not be the same everytime you run the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array type in a function parameter (including constructor parameters) has special rules that make it behave as if it was declared with as pointer instead, for almost all purposes.

So

```
    Vector3d(float values[3])
```

is actually

```
    Vector3d(float* values)
```

So, in the first snippet, you are just storing a pointer value pointing to `arr` from `main` into `data_ptr`. `arr` in `main` lives until the end of `main`. So you can still access it. When you access `data_ptr[i]` you are actually accessing `arr[i]`.

Nothing is copying an array in this code. You are only manipulating pointers. If you want arrays to have copy behavior like other types, then use `std::array` instead of built-in arrays. `std::array` behaves like any scalar or class type, while built-in arrays have weird behaviors inherited from C.

---

In the second snippet you are explicitly copying the elements from `arr` into a new array `data_ptr`. The `data_ptr` array is distinct from the `arr` array and since their lifetimes overlap they must be located at distinct addresses. What I said above still applies though: `values` is just a pointer to `arr`.

Comment: Thank you. And just to be clear, if I alter the constructor as in the second snippet, I am still not copying any data, correct?

Comment: @rocksNwaves In the second snippet you are copying each element individually. So that's a copy.

Answer (score 0):

(This ignores the fact that your class is not owning the memory for some reason).

No, there is no copy despite the appearances.
I have invented my own rule to deal with (legacy) c-arrays.
Always pass them by reference. (Yes, you can pass a c-array by reference explicitly).

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vector3dR {

    public:
        float* data_ptr;

    public:
        Vector3dR(float (&values)[3]) {
            data_ptr = &values[0];
        }
        
};

int main(){
    float arr[] = {3, 4, 5};
    Vector3dRef vec = Vector3dRef(arr);
    
    cout << (vec.data_ptr[0] == arr[0]) << endl;
}
```

The reasoning is that this is what the compiler see anyway, and adding the `&` is clearer for the coder.
In other words, `float[3]` as parameter is a "lie", while `float(&)[3]` is not.

In modern code, just use `std::array<T, N>`, which precisely wraps `T[N]` to have the expected behavior.
`std::array<T, N>&` will bind and `std::array<T, N>` will copy (not what you want here perhaps).

```
        Vector3dR(std::array<float, 3>& values) {  // doesn't copy
            data_ptr = &values[0];
        }
        
};

int main(){
    std::array<float, 3> arr = {{3, 4, 5}};
    Vector3dRef vec = Vector3dRef(arr);
```